# How do I read in FILE contents in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I just need something similar to Fstream to read file IO in QML. Why is there no file IO?

Answer (score 14):

If your file is plain text you can use XMLHttpRequest.  For example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("GET", "mydir/myfile.txt");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        var response = xhr.responseText;
        // use file contents as required
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old question but you might be still interested in answer.
Here it is: [Reading a line from a .txt or .csv file in qml (Qt Quick)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894531/reading-a-line-from-a-txt-or-csv-file-in-qml-qt-quick)

In short, you have here explained how to read files in QML: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Reading_and_writing_files_in_QML

All you need is to extend QML with C++.

Comment: The linked solution involves reading it in C++ and making that available to QML - it isn't a solution using only QML and the Qt Javascript engine.

Answer (score 4):

QML has no built-in file I/O. But - judging from the tone of your post - you already knew that.

**How do I read in FILE contents in QML?**

You can extend QML's functionalities using C++.

The [Getting Started Programming with QML](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/gettingstartedqml.html) tutorial from the Qt Reference Documentation shows you how to build a text editor. This includes file I/O using C++.

**Why is there no file I/O?**

Because QML is based on JavaScript, and JavaScript has no built-in file I/O either.

QML is designed as an (easy) way to build a user interface. You need an actual program to do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

There is built-in file I/O available for QML with the Felgo SDK (formerly V-Play) [`FileUtils`](https://felgo.com/doc/felgo-fileutils/). It works cross-platform on desktop, iOS and Android. More info and examples are also in the [latest blog post](https://blog.felgo.com/updates/release-2-17-0-firebase-cloud-storage-downloadable-resources-at-runtime-and-native-file-access-on-all-platforms).

It looks like this:

```
var documentsData = fileUtils.readFile("subfolder/file.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function readConfigFile() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    var configaddress = "File:///" + root + "/webconfig.txt" //root = "c:/folder/file.ini";
    console.log(configaddress);
    xhr.open("GET", configaddress);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var response = xhr.responseText;
            var js = JSON.parse(response)
            if (js.address != "") {
                service_address = js.address
            }
            // use file contents as required
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What do you want to read the file for?... if its simple data.. then you are probably better off using QML Offline storage API. [Look for that section here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeglobalobject.html).

If you want to deploy a db with your application read [this conversation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/3357).

If you really want to read the file still, learn C++ and expose your code to QML. That, then, is beyond the scope of my answer.