# Qt Expected Character ')' Error

Tags: qt, templates, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2

I am getting the following error:

> Debugging starts QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe
>   environment. QML Debugger: Waiting for connection on port 55186...
>   QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component qrc:/main.qml:23
>   Expected token `)'

Line 23

```
QFile, file("C://new.txt");
```

The Code

```
#include <QIODevice>
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQml 2.2



ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("File Editor")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&File")
           MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&Open")
                onTriggered: {
                    var message = ("Hello World!");
                    QFile, file("C://new.txt");
                    file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
                    QTextStream out(&file);
                    out << %message%;
                }
                }
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("E&xit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    MainForm {
        anchors.fill: parent
        button1.onClicked: messageDialog.show(qsTr("Button 1 pressed"))
        button2.onClicked: messageDialog.show(qsTr("Button 2 pressed"))
        button3.onClicked: messageDialog.show(qsTr("Button 3 pressed"))
    }

    MessageDialog {
        id: messageDialog
        title: qsTr("May I have your attention, please?")

        function show(caption) {
            messageDialog.text = caption;
            messageDialog.open();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess `'C://new.txt'` should be `"C://new.txt"`.

Comment: Why do you //? Escape character is \\ so maybe you're referring to `QFile, file("C:\\new.txt");` instead of `QFile, file('C://new.txt');`? So I'm talking about \\ and ". More than that, as @SimonWarta says, you cannot mix `C++` code with `QML`...

Comment: You are mixing QML code and C++ code. That cannot work. If you need additional help, please format your pasted code correctly first (add 4 spaces in front of each line before you paste to Stack Overflow). Otherwise it is too hard to read for others.

Comment: Signal handlers in QML accepts *only* javascript code, not C++ code. What you can do is call a C++ method (a `SLOT` or a [`Q_INVOKABLE`](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Calling_Qt_class_methods_from_QML)) or [create a custom QML type](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8915904/2538363) for the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by [Simon Warta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2013738/simon-warta) and [BaCaRoZzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538363/bacarozzo) in the comments, you cannot use C++ in QML. You need to use Javascript and create your own custom type for handling file input and output.

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894531/reading-a-line-from-a-txt-or-csv-file-in-qml-qt-quick).